# Npgsql package gives System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql, c#-8.0

The simple stupid error but I can't find any solution on internet.
I get a error with a simple project .NETFramework v4.6.1 with NuGet PackageReference.
Did I forget a specific reference?

The simple code in the test method:

```
var host = "localhost";
var port = 5432
var database = "postgres";
var username = "postgres";
var password = "password";
var connectionString = $"Host={host};Port={port};Database={database};Username={username};Password={password};";
var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
try
{
    connection.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var rtle = ex.InnerException as ReflectionTypeLoadException;
    var exceptions = rtle.LoaderExceptions;
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^
    // System.TypeLoadException: The 'DisposeAsync' method of type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlBinaryExporter' of assembly 'Npgsql, Version=4.1.3.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' has no implementation.
}
```

All PackageReference in the project.csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="4.1.3.1" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.abstractions" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.assert" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.core" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.extensibility.core" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.extensibility.execution" Version="2.1.0" />
```

The exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: Une exception a été levée par l'initialiseur de type pour 'Npgsql.TypeMapping.GlobalTypeMapper'. ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Impossible de charger un ou plusieurs des types requis. Extrayez la propriété LoaderExceptions pour plus d'informations.
   à System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   à System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   à System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   à Npgsql.TypeMapping.GlobalTypeMapper.SetupGlobalTypeMapper() dans C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\TypeMapping\GlobalTypeMapper.cs:ligne 161
   à Npgsql.TypeMapping.GlobalTypeMapper..cctor() dans C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\TypeMapping\GlobalTypeMapper.cs:ligne 32
   --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
   à Npgsql.TypeMapping.GlobalTypeMapper.get_Instance()
   à Npgsql.TypeMapping.ConnectorTypeMapper..ctor(NpgsqlConnector connector) dans C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\TypeMapping\ConnectorTypeMapper.cs:ligne 60
   à Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<LoadDatabaseInfo>d__149.MoveNext() dans C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:ligne 431
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   à Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>d__148.MoveNext() dans C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:ligne 423
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   à Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<AllocateLong>d__28.MoveNext() dans C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\ConnectorPool.cs:ligne 249
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   à System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   à Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<<Open>g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext() dans C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:ligne 297
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
   à System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   à Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open() dans C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:ligne 119
   à Postgresql.Tests.Queries.Test() dans C:\Git\Postgresql.Tests\Queries.cs:ligne 20
```

Comment: catch the exception; the inner exception (`.InnerException`) sounds like it is a `ReflectionTypeLoadException`, so: look at that: `var rtle = ex.InnerException as ReflectionTypeLoadException;` - then look at the loader exceptions: `if (rtle is object) { ... look at rtle.LoaderExceptions ...}` - and see what they say; my guess would be a missing assembly binding redirect

Comment: The 'DisposeAsync' method of type 'Npgsql.NpgsqlBinaryExporter' of assembly 'Npgsql, Version=4.1.3.1, Culture=neutral, 'PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7' has no implementation.

Found in ex.InnerException.LoaderExceptions

Comment: OK, *that* sounds like something to log with Shay Rojansky ("roji"), via https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues

Comment: Done, https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/3049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *looks* like this is a packaging error that has been fixed in the code, but not yet deployed; you *might* be able to fix this temporarily by adding a package reference to your local project:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" Version="1.1.1" />
```

(then clean the solution - in particular make sure that the /obj and /bin etc are removed, before rebuilding)

Comment: Don't forget to: clean solution;  delete the obj/ folder, build. (please add in your answer)
See https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2923 
  or https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/3049